# How to route ProtonVPN while hosting a website

Tags: networking, vpn, domain, web-hosting

I recently purchased a domain and am looking to host it locally. However, I've run into a caveat. I don't want to disclose my IP or general location. Along with my Domain, I also purchased a month-to-month subscription to ProtonVPN basic. I would like to have ProtonVPN not automatically connect to another server and also to hide my IP when I am hosting the website.

The tutorials I have read so far has not worked, and there are none for ProtonVPN.

Is there any way I could do this?

Comment: oh god please someone respond

Comment: How are you handling DNS? One option would be to use a dynamic DNS service that automatically reassigns your hosted domain to your new ProtonVPN IP if it meets certain criteria (not being your public IP).